При переносе exe файла в другую папку вызвает исключение "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException"
У меня в проекте программа черпает некоторую информацию из нескольких файлов, которые находятся в папке "Program settings", расположенной в папке Debug. Если я копирую экзешник и вставляю его, к примеру, на рабочий стол, то при запуске программы выскакивает исключение "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException". Как можно сделать так, чтобы программа по - прежнему черпала неку информацию из файла, но при этом при переносе экзешника в другую директорию не выскакивало это исключение?

Убрать относительные пути и использовать абсолютные, либо использовать системные переменные путей типа %user%

Каким образом, по-вашему программа должна узнать, откуда брать файлы? Это должно задано пользователем в настройках или как? Или мы за вас должны это придумать?
